# Getting exception: weblogic.management.ManagementException:

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

Hi While I am trying to start my Weblogic I am getting exception.

Weblogic 10.3
**Java :** jdk 1.6.18
**OS :** windows 7

Stack trace :

> weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Management:141266]Parsing Failure in config.xml: 
>   org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z
>       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.(RuntimeAccessImpl.java:127)
>       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(RuntimeAccessService.java:41)
>       at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
>       at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
>       at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:802)
>       at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:489)
>       at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)
>       at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)

Comment: perhaps you made a mistake in config.xml?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. But I am using mac. Have you tried installing JDK 1.7 and try setting it your JAVA_HOME?